# How to quickly show areas on a map (with OpenStreetMap?)

Tags: openstreetmap

Yesterday I wanted to quickly indicate some areas (lat/lon rectangles) on a map, like OpenStreetMap. And I couldn't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions? It doesn't have to be interactive, just a bitmap image of the map, with the areas showing as rectangles, would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you went to openstreetmap.org web site, they use OpenLayers for the rendering. There are examples on how to do major things with openlayers:
Draw graphics: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.9.1/examples/draw-feature.html
Simple boxes: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/boxes-vector.html

Answer (score 0):

Try **Easymap** an OpenStreetMap base with the option of adding markers (points)
Experimental is Lines and Polygons >> have checked and both work well.

http://osmtools.de/easymap/index.php?page=editor&lang=en

also in German (Deutsch)